# Código parando após primeiro laço #C

Tags: c, for

Gostaria de saber porque o código abaixo é encerrado após a primeira volta do laço de repetição.

```
void main (void)
{
printf("\t===== LIVROS EDITORA =====\n\n");

int livros, i;
char segmento, incentivo;

printf("Qual o numero de livros encomendados?\n");
scanf("%d", &livros);

    for(i=0; livros != -1 && i<=livros; i++)
    {
        printf("\nQual o segmento do livro N %d?\n",i+1);
        scanf("%s", &segmento);

        printf("\nPossui incentivos fiscais o livro de N %d?\n", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &incentivo);
    }

}
```

Obs.: O laço deve rodar enquanto i for < ou igual a quantidade de livros que a pessoa encomendou.

E deve parar caso a quantidade de livros seja -1.

Answer (score -1):

Sua pergunta falta detalhes. Mas analisando o código creio que pode ser problema na leitura, gerando falha de segmentação e consequentemente o fim do programa.

Você faz a leitura de uma string em um caractere único. Veja que você faz:

```
char segmento;

...
scanf("%s", &segmento);
```

tente substituir por:

```
char segmento;

...
scanf("%c ", &segmento);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Imagine ser assim. A pergunta do cara falta detalhes, eu tento ajudar e tomo downvote.